# How do you deal with Xcode's irritating auto completion behaviour for blocks?

Tags: xcode

XCode's auto completion can sometimes be a pain in the butt, here an example:

[image]

It seems impossible to just type in some content to replace the completionHander placeholder without deleting the entire highlighted section of text - if I hit tab and start typing then Xcode deletes everything highlighted in blue, when what we want to do is keep the ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) part and type in our own content in place of the completionHandler placeholder.

Are there any tricks to keep auto completion enabled for cases when its useful, but to get this and similar examples usable instead of unusable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, but instead of starting typing, just press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Xcode will expand the selection into a block with empty implementation.

#### Before:

[image: before]

#### After:

[image: after]

Answer (score 1):

When the placeholder for the block is highlighted, press <kbd>Return</kbd>. It'll be replaced by the complete block declaration and a set of empty braces, with a highlighted placeholder inside for you to start typing code for the block's body; e.g.

```
[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location 
               completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                                     <code>
                                 }]
```

Comment: Thanks, Michal's answer got there a minute before your's so I have to accept his answer.